# Group isomorphism with a fixed element

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group. For $c \in G$ a fixed element let us define a new operation in $G$ defined by $a*b=a\cdot c \cdot b$

Prove that the funtion $f: (G, \cdot)\longrightarrow  (G, *) $ given by $f(x)=c^{-1} \cdot x$ is an isomorphism

my attempt:

$f(x)=c^{-1}x $
$f(y)=c^{-1}y $

$f(x)= f(y): c^{-1}x = c^{-1}y  \Longrightarrow{x=y} $

How do I test for surjectivity and morphism?

Thanks

Comment: what did you try for those two?

Comment: Not strictly speaking a duplicate of the linked question. That is asking for a proof that $(G,*)$ is indeed a group (with $c^{-1}$ being the identity). This question seems to assume that fact already, and is now asking for a proof that a particular map out of the original group $G$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

As now pointed out, there is the issue of whether the new operation makes $G$ into a group.  Suppose it does.

Given $y\in G $, we have $f (cy)=c^{-1}cy=y$, proving surjectivity.

Now for morphism, you have to use the new rule.  $f (xy) =c^{-1}xy$.  But $f (x)*f (y)=(c^{-1}x)*(c^{-1}y)=c^{-1}xcc^{-1}y=c^{-1}xy=f (xy) $.